# Spring Security @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to access the current active profile via the Spring Security @PreAuthorize annotation like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_' + #{ environment.activeProfiles[0] } + '_ROLE')")
```

I'm receiving the following exception:

EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'

Is there a way to do this without writing a custom expression handler?

Comment: You are missing quotes before "#" and after "}" as below :
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_' + '#{ environment.activeProfiles[0] }' + '_ROLE')")

Comment: Anything inside the single quotes doesn't get evaluated. I need the #{} expression to be evaluated by spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working in a convoluted way. Seems like it should be more straightforward. This feels like a hack:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_' + #profile + '_ROLE')")
public void method(@Value("#{ environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]?.toUpperCase() }") String profile)
```